Etymology of 郵便
What is the rough etymology of 郵便 (mail service / mail / postal matter)? Or how do 郵 (mail) and 便 (convenience) come together to form the meaning of mail service / mail / postal matter? Specifically, how does 便 (convenience) contribute to the meaning of mail service / mail / postal matter?

Another note in general is that it's probably not helpful to think of kanji compounds as though they were formed by referring to one-word English glosses. Such shortcuts might help you initially, but if you find such explanations insufficient, I recommend checking Japanese-language kanji dictionaries.

Too bad that I found this in the review queue with heavy downvotes... It is a historical twist and 便 here does not actually mean "convenience". I believe that you'd not find a "mail" or similar definition for 便 in a Chinese dictionary.
便 in the modern Japanese has a sense "a transportation (of car, train, plane, or data etc)". The reason why 便 has come to mean such things is because it was employed as a kanji spelling of a native word たより (cf. 国訓), whose main meaning is "help, dependency, reliance," but which has a derived sense "(medium of) message; messenger".
So, in this case, both kanji in 郵便 just stand for "mail" or "mail carrier".

So 便 is used in 郵便 for its pronunciation instead of its lexical meaning?

@Pheonix No, as I wrote, it does have a meaning like "message" in today's Japanese which is nonexistent in Chinese (or as kanji's original meaning). It is somewhat like an English word borrowed from French but gained a totally different sense during its own development, such as party as "gathering".

@broccolliforest Just to clarify, would "mail" (or maybe "letter"?) be a more accurate meaning of 便, or are there other fairly common uses of it that I'm unaware of?

@Pheonix Yes, as a Japanese-specific sense: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BE%BF#Etymology_2_2. If I'd say in a single word, "message" or "transmission". How it acquired such a meaning is as what I explained.

Alright thanks for answering my question when nobody else did! 便 having the additional meanings of "message" or "transmission" makes more sense here rather than only meaning convenience. Although I don't know anything about the history behind party and gathering.

Also this additional meaning seems to be exemplified by 便り.
